# Problem with MiKTeK after updating

Tags: miktex-update

I have recently made an update of MiKTeX on Windows 10.
Now if I try to open a tex file I receive messages of system error complaining that certain files are missing, and suggesting me to try reinstalling the application.
The missing files are:

MiKTeX210300-hunspell.ddl

MiKTeX210300-log4cxx.ddl

MiKTeX210300-lua53.ddl

MiKTeX210300-poppler-Qt.ddl

I have checked that in my MiKTeX directory (...\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64) are actually present the files
MiKTeX221200-hunspell.ddl,
MiKTeX221200-log4cxx.ddl,
MiKTeX221200-lua53.ddl and
MiKTeX221200-poppler-Qt.ddl,
which I guess are more recent versions of the files than the required ones.

On the other hand, if I try to access miktex-console.exe in order to uninstall the application, I get the same type of system error messages, complaining this time that the missing files are

MiKTeX221200-ui-Qt.ddl

MiKTeX221200-setup.ddl

MiKTeX221200-loc.ddl

MiKTeX221200-packagemanager.ddl

And I have checked that in my directory there are the files
MiKTeX210300-ui-Qt.ddl,
MiKTeX210300-setup.ddl,
MiKTeX210300-loc.ddl and
MiKTeX210300-packagemanager.ddl,
so in this case presumably older versions of the files than the required ones!

What should I do now? Does it make sense to try reinstalling MiKTeX, if I am unable to uninstall before the older version which does not work any more?

Comment: well this looks all rather outdated. In my miktex all dll have the number 230100. Check if there are updates in admin *and* user mode of the console.

Comment: I agree with you. I have recently installed MiKTeX on another computer, and the number of the dll files is 230100 as well. However, on the computer where I have the problem, I cannot run the miktex console in either admin or user mode, apparently just because the needed dll files are missing.

Comment: Use the Microsoft way of removing programs (apps as they call it nowadays) to remove your MikTeX installation. Download the latest MikTeX basic installation program and after **rebooting** your computer perform a fresh installation. There is a major upgrade in MikTeX between these two versions, that can not be solved using the *upgrade* function.

Comment: I have tried to remove MiKTeX using the App tool in the Windows Settings, but I receive the same system error messages about missing dll files, as when I try to run the miktex console. If instead I select MiKTeX in the Windows Control Panel and then click on 'Uninstall', then nothing happens. Is there another way to remove a program?

Comment: There is ... Open `Explorer` Delete the MikTex Folder in where ever you installed it (Usually Program Files). Go to the `AppData` folder and delete the `MikTeX` folder in `<username>\Local\MikTeX`. If you feel confident, open the `Registry` and delete all keys containing the word `MikTeX`. That removes almost all keys related to MikTeX. Then reinstall a fresh download from the MikTeX repository, immediately do an `update` to obtain the most recent version. Install all other packages after that.

Comment: Thank you alchemist, I followed your hints and the problem seems to be solved.